# Find repeated number in an array of unique numbers

Tags: arrays

There is an array where except one number (say magic-number) all are unique. The magic-number
repeats itself more than half times the size of the array. e.g. 2, 10, 10, 10, 3. Find the magic-number without
using any extra-space and without sorting it. Now is there any method to do it in O(n).

Comment: By "without using any extra space" you mean you can't, say, allocate another list of searched numbers? Basically, only a pointer/index to the list is valid?

Comment: of course you will always need pointer and index

Answer (score 2):

Check each element against its neighbors, if any are equal then you have found the number. O(N)

If the first test did not find the number, then you in the following situation:

```
10,2,10,3,10.
```

In this case, the first number in the array is the magic number. O(1)